# <Your App> is having trouble with Google Play services.Please try again. Only on 4.4.X OS devices

Tags: android, google-drive-api, google-play-services

We have an android app on Play Store for last 2 years. We are trying to connect the Google Drive API using play services inside the app.

Things are working fine for all the android OS except 4.4.X.  In 4.4.X OS devices while trying to login to the Google Account most of the users are getting the error (as reported by them) like :

> " is having trouble with Google Play services.Please try again."

Does anyone know how to fix this issue?.  This is Not reproducing on all 4.4.X devices.

Comment: hey how did you fix this issue?

Comment: After Updating the Google Play Service, My issue was solved.

Answer (score 11):

If you are having troubles with your virtual devices when running things like Google maps etc.; try creating a new virtual device with Google Play Store incorporated

[image: virtual device with the message]

[image: possible solution]

Comment: This works on newer API, but doesn't work on API 19.

Comment: @abdulla_malik don't denounce it as a waste of time because it did not solve your problem specifically. It's a valid answer, and I upvoted it, as I would not have realized on my own that I needed the Play Store installed

Comment: it worked for me. my fault was using a device which too old.

Comment: how to incorporate PlayStore to an emulator?

Answer (score 6):

1. On your Android phone, go to Settings.
2. Click on Apps.
3. Click Google Play services.
4. Click on Permissions.
5. Ensure all permission settings are turned on.

Comment: Even that didn't help, one interesting thing i noticed is that when i install the local debug build its working fine but same device is not working with play store build.

Comment: After further investigation we found out that this issue happens when we use Prod cert to sign the apk(only on 4.4.X os version).
Its working fine with debug and android studio cert signed apk.

Any recommended steps to fix this issue?

Answer (score 2):

I've had the same issue as reported above after updating my app dependencies from `com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.1` to `..:16.1.0` (or `..:17.0.0`). The problem for was that the installed version of Google Play Services on my device (a Zebra TC51 running Android 6.0.1 in this case) is rather old and is managed by our customer using a mobile device management solution (MDM) that is very conservative. Rolling back to `..:15.0.1` or updating Google Play Services to the latest version would *both* solve this issue for me. Sadly, I cannot force our customers to update Google Play Services (although I'd like them to update obviously).

Reproducing this is straightforward by just installing an older Google Play Services (download the July 2018 version for example, [v12.8.74](https://www.apkmirror.com/apk/google-inc/google-play-services/google-play-services-12-8-74-release/google-play-services-12-8-74-000300-204998136-android-apk-download/download/). Set your dependency to 16.0.1 or newer and you'll get the above error message.

I haven't been able to find an overview that lists the compatibility between versions of the installed Google Play Services APK and which versions of the `com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps` dependency are supported.

Also, have a look at the [Overview of Google Play Services](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/overview) where it is explained how the included dependency (in your app) and the installed client library (on the device) depend on one another.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your Google Play Services is *updated*

Answer (score 1):

For me worked: `Settings` > `Apps and Notifications` > `Google Play Store` > `Permissions` > `All ON`

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by following the instructions on setting up Firebase on a new project. I encountered the "Try again" prompt until I added `firebase-core` to the project.

Answer (score 0):

Opening google maps once and the trying my map fixed the problem