# How properly ask permission to use Nearby service?

Tags: android, ibeacon, ibeacon-android, google-nearby, android-ibeacon

This problem appeared only in android 10. I am using Nearby service for iBeacon. In my manifest I'm asking permission ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION and before start nearby service I check if my app has this permission been granted. So why i have this error and how should I properly ask permission to use nearby service? Also i don't like description in asking permission dialog. My app don't use microphone. It frightens users!

```
Nearby.getMessagesClient(this, new MessagesOptions.Builder()
                .setPermissions(NearbyPermissions.BLE)
                .build())
                .subscribe(getNearbyPendingIntent(), options);
```

[image: google play service error]

[image: asking permission]

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54597025/how-to-resolve-app-is-having-trouble-with-google-play-services-please-try-agai

Comment: Were you able to solve this?

Comment: Actually, I don't use "+" in all my dependencies^ but thank you for suggestion.